# Would it be possible to post a call for a job on the WordPress Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, jobs, wordpress-se

Would it be possible to post a call for WordPress professionals to work on a project at the WordPress Stack Exchange? If not the job, then to post a question of where could I find good, professional WordPress developers?

If no to both of the above, can somebody here give me some pointers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, both subjects would be very much *off topic*. Stack Exchange sites are for *questions and their answers* only, they are not there for other community-engagement posts.

You'll have to find a different venue to access the Wordpress community, like a mailinglist or discussion board. If you have more than 20 reputation points on Wordpress.stackexchange.com, you could also try asking around in the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).

You could also pay http://careers.stackoverflow.com to access developers listed there.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters Thank you, the careers @ stackoverflow works. I was looking for info like this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [About](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about) page, the following is considered on-topic on Wordpress Stack Exchange:

- Theme and plugin development
- Development and management best practices
- Server configuration for WordPress

Both the subjects you've mentioned are off-topic for the site.

> If no to both of the above, can somebody here give me some pointers?

You can try [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). I suggest you read the [FAQ for the site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq) first, though.